# Get-ChildItem high memory usage

Tags: powershell, memory, get-childitem

I want to scan some large directories with millions of files for summary with 2nd level directory names, size and count of files in each recursively. I left the code running for a couple of hours, but it got stuck somewhere in the middle due to PowerShell consuming 13GB of memory. Any idea why the memory usage went so high?

```
$mailboxes = Get-ChildItem E:\data -Directory |
             Get-ChildItem -Directory |
             Select -ExpandProperty FullName

foreach ($line in $mailboxes) {
    $s = $line.split("\\")
    $files = Get-ChildItem $line -File -Recurse -Include *.eml
    $mailbox_path = $line
    $mailbox = $s[-1]
    $size = $files | Measure-Object Length -Sum | select -ExpandProperty Sum
    $count = $files.Count
    "$mailbox_path`t$mailbox`t$size`t$count" |
        Out-File 'D:\scripts\summary.txt' -Append
}
```

Comment: Does the memory usage gradually keep increasing as the script runs, or is it just in the middle that it goes up?

Comment: Does it help when you replace `-Include *.eml` with `-Filter *.eml` and/or collect only the sizes of the files in the variable `$files` (`$files = Get-ChildItem ... | Select-Object -Expand Length`)?

Answer (score 0):

See if this is any better

```
$mailboxes = Get-ChildItem E:\data -Directory | Get-ChildItem -Directory
$OutputPath = 'D:\scripts\summary.csv'

foreach($line in $mailboxes) {

$files = Get-ChildItem $line.FullName -File -Recurse -Filter *.eml
$size = $files | Measure-Object Length -Sum | select -ExpandProperty Sum


[pscustomobject]@{MailBoxPath = $line.FullName;MailBox = $line.BaseName;FileSize = $size;FileCount = $files.count} | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Comment: Correctly using the PowerShell pipeline should also minimize memory consumption.  
To *correctly* use the PowerShell pipeline, you should avoid the variable assignments (like `$mailboxes =`) and parenthesis, especially for the mean stream. Thus: `Get-ChildItem E:\data -Directory | Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem $line.FullName -File -Recurse -Filter *.eml ... } | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation -Append`